# VueJS dynamic dropdown - json data not showing in the view

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am making dynamic dropdown lists with Vue.JS , the `Countries` and `Regions` are fetching dynamically but the `Cities` JSON is received but not fetched into the view and there is **no error shown in the console**, I couldn't find my mistake.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <form action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="country"></label>
      <select v-model="country" name="country" class="form-control" @change="loadRegions">
        <option>Select country</option>
        <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id">@{{ country.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="region"></label>
        <select v-model="region" name="region" class="form-control" @change="loadCities">
          <option>Select region</option>
          <option v-for="region in regions" :value="region.id">@{{ region.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="city"></label>
        <select v-model="city" name="city" class="form-control">
          <option>Select city</option>
          <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">@{{ city.name }}</option>
       </select>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
     data() {
      return {
       countries: [],
       regions: [],
       cities: [],
       country:'',
       region:'',
       city:'',
   }
 },

 mounted() {
    this.loadCountries();
  },

   methods: {
    loadCountries() {
       axios.get('/countries')
       .then(response => this.countries = response.data.countries)
       .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },    
    loadRegions() {
       axios.get('/regions', {params: {country: this.country}})
       .then(response => this.regions = response.data.regions)
       .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
    loadCities() {
       axios.get('/cities', {params: {country: this.country, region: this.region}})
       .then(response => this.cities = response.data.cities)
       .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
   }
 })
 </script>
```

[Json object in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMJ0r.png)

[Devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb0zt.png)

Comment: there would be any error in axios. check response ?

Comment: Actually the (localhost:8000/cities?country=n&region=n) is returning objects but in the Vue Devtool it's returning empty array

Comment: no errors? in the controller?

Comment: I've had problems with axios passing multiple parameters, maybe it is related. I've stop using it since the guys there doesn't give a st about the community, things like this: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362#issuecomment-401014489 two years bug, no one there cares about...

Comment: The controller is sending the json data correctly @gil

Comment: I see no errors in your code except the typo mentioned below. What about a screenshot of your Vue Dev Tools.

Comment: Of course , do i update it in the question ?

Comment: just as an experiment, try: `axios.get( \`/cities?country=${this.country}&region=${this.region}\`).....` and see what happens

Comment: @JorgeCampos the last edit returned the same result , json received correctly but not filling in the select box

Comment: ok... can you check something please, after calling the city, inspect your select element and see what was rendered in the html code.

Comment: @JorgeCampos i did that too it's returning empty select box

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't notice it. Try first `this.cities = response.data` only and add `console.log(response.data)`...

Comment: @gil Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: Oh so there is the error... its in the axios. Maybe your params.

Comment: maybe your call to loadCities is happening before the loadRegion finishes which may be passing a null/undefinded region

Comment: Yeah @Jorge has a point, you must have a conditional there to make sure `country` and `region` is not empty before executing the axios.

Comment: I am trying to work on conditional for that case even that i call the loadRegion method first in every try

Comment: You can try also using async/await to make sure it doesn't do the call asynchronous ,take a look: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: or check this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/604

Comment: There is no way i could find to solve this , should i just post that as right answer ?

Answer (score 1):

the mistake is on the last square brackets:

`<option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">@{{ city.name }</option>`

put another..

`<option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">@{{ city.name }}</option>`

Comment: That mistake was just in the post , still nothing changed even with correct syntax